# Форма отправки даных

Tags: php, javascript, html, smtp

Привет всем!)
Подскажите пожалуйста!
Я не понимаю немного процеса отправки письма от ведденого пользователем даных, и отправки ему благодарности за это!
Сначала нужно прописать саму форму в html потом добавить к ней jqueryvalidation , после нужно прописать все в php прикрипляя даные с id , после добавить smtp в php что бы была отправка письма пользователю благодарности за то что он отослал вам свои даные...
Оно должно где то храниться все... 
наверное в логах, или json ...
Я наверное все совсем не правильно понимаю!
Извините за такой вопрос, но я даже не знаю как разобраться в этом без какого то направления!

Answer (score 1):

PHP скрипт получает данные от html формы, валидирует их и если все правильно, то посылает письмо, через функцию mail() или через PHPMailer. Вы можете логировать отправленные письма - в файл или в БД. А лучше не посылать письмо сразу, а писать его в БД. А посылать письма по крону.